# C in JVM? Show errors during programming

Tags: c, jvm, development-environment

A great feature - I think - is, when languages, running in a virtualized way like C# and Java show errors during you're working on the source. Most often IDEs like Eclipse or NetBeans or VisualStudio have the feature to specify errors immediately.

Is there anything like this for C/C++? Just for coding... I'm currently searching for a way to gain the same coding experience with good old C :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse has C and C++ support with the CDT project.  I've never personally used it but I would assume it has everything you want.

http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/

Answer (score 3):

You can program in C++ in Visual Studio and it will give you the same intellisense an error highlighting features you would expect from it's other languages.

Comment: Intellisense, yes, but I haven't seen any error highlighting yet (with VC++ Express 2008).

Answer (score 0):

[Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/features/cpp/index.html) and [Sun Studio](http://developers.sun.com/sunstudio/features/whatsin.jsp) have C/C++ support (Sun Studio seems to have more advanced debugging features).